# How to setup views exposed filter with result between 2 fields values

Tags: views

I have content type called the materials with 2 temperature fields as **Max.** and **Min.**

in the views, there is between operator from filter and normally it use for user could input 2 values to the form for filter.

from my case, I want user could input 1 temperature value in the filter and the views result will be the termperaure between **Max.** and **Min.**  fields.

is that any way could approach this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Views Filters Populate](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_filters_populate) module. It allows you to populate multiple field filters.

Create 2 filters:

1. **Min** (w/ ***Is less than or Equal to*** operator)
2. **Max** (w/ ***Is greater than or Equal to*** operator)

Add an exposed ***Global: Populate filters*** filter with both the **Min**/**Max** filters selected. This will create an exposed filter that will search for items between your **Mix**/**Max** fields.

Answer (score 1):

The [Range](https://www.drupal.org/project/range) module allows you to add a numeric range field to a content type and provides Views filters allowing you to select values within or without the range.